# Trying to find a function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) \ \text{does not exist}$.

Tags: analysis, functions

I am trying to find a function, which will have these two properties and I cannot really succeed in it.

> $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$
>
> $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) \ \text{does not exist}$

Has anyone got any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} \left[A \cos(x^2) + B \sin(x^2)\right]$

Comment: Consider a scaled sine function: $f(x)=x^{-a}\sin(g(x))$, for some $a$ (we can even try taking $a=1$). You know the oscillations will be shrinking in height; what would you have to do to keep them from 'flattening out' completely?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28%28%28sin%28x%5E2%29%2Bcos%28x%5E2%29%29%2Fx%29%27+as+x+goes+to+infinity

Comment: It seems it doesn't work

Comment: @marco11 What do you think your Alpha link shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0\text{ if } x\not\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ but $f'(x)$ doesn't even exist.

Comment: I guess that OP is asking a differentiable function  over $[0,+\infty)$ such $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) \ \text{does not exist}.$ The derivative should exists but not its limit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a function that goes to zero times a function with increasingly fast oscillations.

Comment: Would $\frac{1}{x} \cdot sin(x^{x})$ work?

Comment: x^x isn't necessary, just x^2.